# Why doesn't setLocation() move my label?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have the following code where I try to place a `JLabel` in a custom location on a `JFrame`.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame 
{

    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        new GUI();
    }
    /**
     * 
     */
    public GUI() 
    {
        JLabel addLbl = new JLabel("Add: ");
        add(addLbl);
        addLbl.setLocation(200, 300);
        this.setSize(400, 400);

        // pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to be moving to where I want it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that the `LayoutManager` of the panel is setting the location of the label for you.

What you need to do is set the layout to null:

```
public GUI() {
    setLayout(null);
}
```

This will make it so the frame does not try to layout the components by itself.

Then call [`setBounds(Rectangle)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) on the label.  Like so:

```
addLbl.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(200, 300), addLbl.getPreferredSize()));
```

This should place the component where you want it.

**However**, if you don't have a really great reason to lay out the components by yourself, it's usually a better idea to use `LayoutManagers` to work in your favor.

[Here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) is a great tutorial on getting started with using `LayoutManager`s.

*If you must go without a `LayoutManager` [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) is a good tutorial for going without one.*

Comment: +1 For giving him the answer to his question, but letting him know it's not a good way to do things in general

Answer (score 0):

You put the location code under the frame and it will work but if you want it to work for sure
put the location code in a run while loop. That's what I did to figure it out and it works.